# Can't see object through a certain camera

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I can see my object fine in rendered mode.

I can even see my object fine with a particular camera in rendered mode.

However, when I switch to a particular camera, I can no longer see the object in rendered mode.  I have tried hiding/unhiding, clipping distances in camera settings and on viewport tab, the output looks good in the node editor, and I have gone through all of the solutions I could find on here.  Here is the camera that I can't see the object with:

[image]

Here is the camera that I can see the object with:
[image]

I am not too familiar with depth of field settings yet so it might have to do with that. I thought if I adjusted the aperture settings it would account for that. Here are the settings I thought you would need to see:

[image]
What're your thoughts and thanks!

Tyler

Comment: Please add an image showing the settings for the second camera. Where is the camera aiming at? Are there any objects blocking the camera view? Are you using any "depth of field"? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project.

Comment: @cetaton I edited the question so it would be more relevant and just about to read that link you sent me.  I'll keep you updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles Render Renders all white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82004/cycles-render-renders-all-white) and [Rendered image is just grey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/rendered-image-is-just-grey/55411#55411)

Comment: The link you referred me to was the answer.  Sorry I wasn't able to find that earlier.  Thanks so much for the help man!@cegaton